# Laravel form error message

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I created a form for myself and it was working perfect. I did some rules like: if the user haven't wrote anything in the form or haven't wrote enough, give me some error message. This was working while used the 'former' package instead of the normally used 'form' package. Now I changed my form from "Former" to "Form" and now my error message are gone.. Well my form works and the rules too. If I don't write anything in my form or not at least 3 characters in the title/content section, it should redirect me with the errors I need. This works, but without the error message.

Here is my form:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'Test\\TestController@store')) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('thread', 'Title:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('thread', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('content', 'Body:') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('content', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Add Thread', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

My Controller@store function:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request){
        Thread::create($request->all());
        return redirect(action('Test\\TestController@index'));
    }
```

my Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Thread;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model {
    public $table = 'thread';
    public $fillable = [
        'thread',
        'content',
    ];
}
```

and now the rules ( StoreRequest.php ) :

```
 <?php
namespace App\Http\Requests\Store;


use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class StoreRequest extends Request {

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'thread' => 'required|min:3',
            'content' => 'required|min:3'
        ];
    }

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

The error message was getting automaticly generated. Laravel did that for me. But not anymore.

Does anybody see why?

Comment: Where are you printing the errors? I don't seem them in blade template.

Comment: well I don't print them. Laravel did that for me. I just wrote the rules and laravel automaticly gave me something like: The title section is required - or - the thread section need's to be at least 3 characters long. That's why I don't know why it does'nt do that anymore.

Comment: Laravel doesn't automatically print them for you. You probably had a default template which had errors printed in them.

Comment: yeah maybe right.. so what is the best way to give me that error messages?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#working-with-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the form returned any error with something along these line:

```
@if ($errors->has('name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p> @endif
```

Or you could use [BootForm](https://github.com/adamwathan/bootforms) and let it handle everything for you

Comment: This works but is there a way to say if one of the form sections, or both, aren't like the rules says, then it should give me a error message?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I would highly advise you to refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)